# Nativescript-Drop-Down get value in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I am using the Nativescript-Drop-Down plugin for my nativescript javascript application. My problem is I am unable to trigger the selectedIndexChanged event inside my js file.

In my view_page.xml I have the following

```
<Page
class="page"
navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"
xmlns:dd="nativescript-drop-down">

<dd:DropDown  id="outletnumber" items="
{{ orderNumbers }}" selectedIndex="{{ selectedIndex }}" 
opened="dropDownOpened" 
closed="dropDownClosed"                                    
selectedIndexChanged="dropDownSelectedIndexChanged"
row="1" col="1" /> 
</Page>
```

And in my view_page.js I have this

```
exports.dropDownSelectedIndexChanged(arg){
    console.log("Drop Down selected index changed from :", args);
}
```

I am not seeing a good example on the internet for using javascript with the nativescript-dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

I changed this:

```
exports.dropDownSelectedIndexChanged(arg){
      console.log("Drop Down selected index changed from :", args);
}
```

to this:

```
exports.dropDownSelectedIndexChanged(args){
      console.log("Drop Down selected index changed from :", args);
}
```

A simple issue but seeing it is a new language I am learning, You always suspect the worst. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to see the JavaScript code since according to the complement you have to send the action when selecting the widget with the "args".

```
export function dropDownSelectedIndexChanged(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {
    console.log(`Drop Down selected index changed from ${args.oldIndex} to ${args.newIndex}`);
}
```